# Firebase Hosting deploying two workspaces

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have two workspaces:

```
main
blog
```

Using the [Quickstart Guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/quickstart.html), I have managed to succesfully deploy the `main` workspace to `mycustomdomain.firebaseapp.com`.

My `firebase.json` looks as follows:

```
{
  "firebase": "mycustomdomain",
  "public": "/",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ]
}
```

Note that I use the rewrite to handle clean urls as I am hosting an Angular 1.x website.

Now, I want to upload the content of the `blog` workspace to the domain `mycustomdomain.firebaseapp.com/blog`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
"rewrites": [{
  "source": "/blog/**",
  "destination": "/blog.html"
}, {
  "source": "**",
  "destination": "/index.html"
}]
```

So any request where the path starts with `/blog/` will be handled by `/blog.html`, everything else will be handled by `index.html`.

With this:

- `https://mycustomdomain.firebaseapp.com/` -> `index.html`
- `https://mycustomdomain.firebaseapp.com/blog/` -> `blog.html`

Note that trailing slash in the last URL. Without that, the request would still be served by `index.html`. If you don't want that, change the the first rewrite to `"source": "/blog**"`

This all boils down to [glob pattern matching that Firebase Hosting uses](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/full-config.html#section-glob) to map the path to a destination. Use an online tester to play with them, if you've never done much with them. I just used http://www.globtester.com/ for that.